# how can i check in the data is passing to server from angular to node.js

Tags: node.js, angular

Got the http-service -

```
public addProductsToBag(
    productId: string,
  ): Observable<IAddProductsToBagResponse> {
    const baseUrl = ENDPOINT;

    return this.http.post<IAddProductsToBagResponse>(baseUrl, {
      productId,
    });
  }
```

Got the `productId` (console.logged it).
Sure the endpoints are the same.

The router -

```
router.post(
  "/",
  auth,
  addProductsToBag,
);
```

I do not get anything fron the controller.

The server controller request -

```
interface IAddProductsToBagRequest extends IAuthenticatedRequest {
  readonly body: Readonly<{
    productId: string[];
  }>;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you using express on backend ?

Comment: @RakeshK yes i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, In order to receive json data, you need to enable express's json middleware on the server.

In `server.js` file do following.

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Then you should get the json data.

Edit: First check if your request is getting sent from the frontend.
After checking code, in order to send request you will need to subscribe to that method, then only request will be sent.